# Not using explicit annotation error in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, annotations, ionic-framework

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/production-ready-apps-with-ionic-framework) on linting/annotating/concatenating/uglifying my Ionic application today.

Got through most of it except annotation. I created a gulp task with gulp-ng-annotate, and it seems to have processed all my app Javascript files well as I  see properly annotated files in my dist folder. But when I run my app in browser or on device, some pages don't run with AngularJS throwing the following error:

> Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($scope, $element) is not using
>   explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(<ion-nav-view
>   name="menuContent" class="view-container"
>   nav-view-transition="ios">cope%2C%20%24element)

Of course, it works when strictDi is turned off. So this seems like an annotation issue, but after scanning my app code I still can't locate the problem.

A word of guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.